# C#, Visual Studio: Deleting non-existant event from Form code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm doing a little example project from a tutorial online and I found an event in my form code that I can't seem to get rid of.

```
private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

When I go to label5's properties in the form design, there is NO click event - the box is blank. But when I manually delete the above method from the code, I still get an error. Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: What is the error (and what code is around that error location)?  That would be good to know.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you try to view the form in Visual Studio?

Comment: It means the method is added to another event for another control. Delete the method. Then build the project. Then follow errors and delete the lines which contains `+= new System.EventHandler(label5_Click)` The errors should be in `InitializeComponent` in `YourForm.designer.cs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you delete all references to label5_Click from your form's InitializeComponent function.

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution, but looking through the InitializeComponent function for instances of "label5" showed that one of my other labels somehow had label5's click event referenced in its own, so I was able to find and fix it. Thanks!